# How can I programatically get message sent by one particular user in a closed group that I am a member of in Telegram?

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, python-telegram-bot

How can I programatically get message sent by one particular user in a closed group that I am a member of in Telegram?

My purpose is to get such messages "realtime" and store it in a timeseries database for visualization. I cannot add my bot as a member to this group. I prefer to use python.

Please advice how to do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you *cannot* add bot to the group, then you cannot use telegram bot API and I guess the only remaining solution is to use a something like Telegram client.

For python, [Telethon](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon) and for PHP, [Madelineproto](https://docs.madelineproto.xyz/) are the most popular options that you can use. They are open source MTProto API Telegram client libraries and instead of bot API, they use your account and have most of capabilities that your Telegram application has.